# how to pass a list to a function without using move in mips

Tags: mips32

i want to pass a list to function in mips so that i can do soemthing to that lsit, but my assignment prohibit the move instruction,

tried to pass the address, but they all error

```
addi $fp, $sp, 0
addi $sp, $sp, -4

la $t0, thelist
sw $t0, ($sp)
jal bubblesort

bubblesort: 
    #call function
    addi $sp, $sp, -8   #push 8 bytes to store $fp and $ra
    sw $ra, 4($sp)
    sw $fp, ($sp)

    #copy $sp to $fp
    addi $fp, $sp, 0

    #allocate local variable
    addi $sp, $sp, -16  #i, j,  listaddress, size

    #initialize i j n
    lw $t0, 8($fp)
    sw $t0, -12($fp)    # listaddress
    lw $t1, size        
    sw $0, -8($fp)      #i = 0
    sw $0, -4($fp)      #j = 0

    loop1:
        #condition
        lw $t0, -8($fp)     #load i
        lw $t1, size        #the actual n
        addi $t1, $t1, -1   #n = n - 1
        beq $t0, $t1, end   #if i == n-1, jump to end

        loop2:
            lw $t0, -4($fp)     #load j
            lw $t1, size    #load n
            addi $t1, $t1, -1   #n = n - 1
            beq $t0, $t1, exit1 #if j == n-1, jump to exit1

            #swap section
            lw $t1, thelist     #$t1 = list address         
            sll $t0, $t0, 2     #j = j*4 
            add $t3, $t1, $t0   #address of list[j]
            lw $t4, ($t3)       #list[j]
            lw $t5, 4($t3)      #list[j+1]
            slt $t2, $t5, $t4   
            beq $t2, $0, exit2  #if list[j] < list[j+1], jump to loop2
            #swap
            add $t2, $t5, 0     #temp = list[j+1]
            add $t5, $t4, 0     #list[j+1] = list[j]
            add $t4, $t2, 0     #list[j] = temp

            sw $t5, ($t3)
            sw $t6, 4($t3)

            lw $t0, -4($fp)
            addi $t0, $t0, 1    #j = j+1
            sw $t0, -4($fp)
            j loop2

            exit2:
            lw $t0, -4($fp)
            addi $t0, $t0, 1    #j = j+1
            sw $t0, -4($fp)
            j loop2

            exit1:  
            lw $t0, -8($fp)
            addi $t0, $t0, 1
            sw $t0, -8($fp)
            j loop1 
    end:
    lw $v0, -12($fp)
    addi $sp, $sp 12
    lw $fp, ($sp)
    lw $ra, 4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can access $t registers inside your functions. There is no need to store it on the stack before. If you load your list to $t10 for example, you can easily access it inside of your function. Also: Instead of move, you can always use add. I can't run your code, since it is not a complete example. How is your list stored?